# Find files based on MD5 and delete

Tags: shell, hashsum

I want to delete same file with different names scattered in folders.
This command works fine for searching and listing the files.
Then I manually delete the files.

Is it possible to add delete option to the below command ?

```
find /folder -type f -exec md5sum {} + | grep '^aafa26a6610d357d8e42f44bc7e76635'
```

Comment: If you know the size of the file, you would be able to potentially speed it up considerably by only computing the checksums of the files with the exact same size (`-size 12345c -exec md5sum {} +` for a file size of 12345 bytes for instance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
find ... | awk '{$1 = "rm" ; print } ' | bash
```

this will replace actual md5sum (`aaf...`) by rm.

this will not work if filename have a special character in it, neither if file is write protected (replace `rm` by `rm -f` ).

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is below. Replace `rm` with `rm -f` if required. Also, add `-n1` to `xargs` (removing the `rm`) to have it print the arguments passed to it (for validation purposes).

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk '$1 == "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" {printf "%s\0", substr($0, 35)}' | xargs -r0 rm
```

Note this method *does* handle spaces in filenames and/or folders.

**TO MATCH MULTIPLE MD5 HASHES**

1. Create a text file containing the hashes you want to search for, one per line, say `hashes.txt`
2. `awk '{printf "%s%s", NR-1 ? "|" : "", $1}' hashes.txt` will reformat this into a single line of pipe `|` separated hashes.
3. Use this variant of the original command to match hashes using regex rather than an exact string match: `find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk '$1 ~ "^('$(awk '{printf "%s%s", NR-1 ? "|" : "", $1}' hashes.txt)')$" {printf "%s\0", substr($0, 35)}' | xargs -r0 -n1`
4. In step 3 above, remove `-n1` and replace with `rm` or `rm -f` to actually perform the file deletions.

Comment: Seems to work as intended

Comment: How could you add the ability to match more than one MD5 to this one liner?

Comment: @JCats See my update.